# Original Alexnet Implementation(Benchmark)

Tags: machine-learning, lua, neural-network, caffe, torch

I have a question about Alexnet model.I have re-implemented the Alexnet model in Torch from BVLC caffe model. But I am getting 0 percent top-1 accuracy all the time even after 1 million iterations with batch size set to 256. I was wondering if someone can help me with what is wrong in my model. This is the model that I wrote:

```
net = nn.Sequential()
net:add(cudnn.SpatialConvolution(3, 96, 11, 11, 4, 4, 0, 0, 1):learningRate('bias', 2):weightDecay('bias', 0))
net:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))
net:add(cudnn.SpatialCrossMapLRN(5))
net:add(cudnn.SpatialMaxPooling(3,3, 2,2, 0,0):ceil())                                                                     

net:add(cudnn.SpatialConvolution(96,256,5,5,1,1,2,2,2):learningRate('bias', 2):weightDecay('bias', 0))
net:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))
net:add(cudnn.SpatialCrossMapLRN(5))
net:add(cudnn.SpatialMaxPooling(3,3,2,2,0,0):ceil())

net:add(cudnn.SpatialConvolution(256, 384, 3,3, 1,1, 1,1,1):learningRate('bias', 2):weightDecay('bias', 0))
net:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))

net:add(cudnn.SpatialConvolution(384, 384, 3,3, 1,1, 1,1,2):learningRate('bias', 2):weightDecay('bias', 0))
net:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))

net:add(cudnn.SpatialConvolution(384, 256, 3,3, 1,1, 1,1,2):learningRate('bias', 2):weightDecay('bias', 0))
net:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))
net:add(cudnn.SpatialMaxPooling(3,3,2,2,0,0):ceil())

--net:add(nn.View(256*6*6))
net:add(nn.View(-1):setNumInputDims(3))
net:add(nn.Linear(256*6*6, 4096):learningRate('weight', 1):learningRate('bias', 2):weightDecay('weight', 1):weightDecay('bias', 0))
--net:add(nn.BatchNormalization(4096))
net:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))
net:add(nn.Dropout(0.5))
net:add(nn.Linear(4096, 4096):learningRate('weight', 1):learningRate('bias', 2):weightDecay('weight', 1):weightDecay('bias', 0))
--net:add(nn.BatchNormalization(4096))
net:add(cudnn.ReLU(true))
net:add(nn.Dropout(0.5))
net:add(nn.Linear(4096, opt.nClasses):learningRate('weight', 1):learningRate('bias', 2):weightDecay('weight', 1):weightDecay('bias', 0))
```

And this is how I have initialized the weights:

```
-- initialize the model
  local function weights_init(m)
    local name = torch.type(m)
    if name:find('Convolution') then
      m.weight:normal(0.0, 0.01)
      m.bias:fill(0)
    elseif name:find('BatchNormalization') then
      if m.weight then m.weight:normal(1.0, 0.02) end
      if m.bias then m.bias:fill(0) end
    end
  end
  net:apply(weights_init)
```

Any pointers will be much appreciated! 
Thank you so much for your help,

Comment: I don't see a Softmax in your model, where is it?

Comment: I have added the Softmax layer as well but it did not work and the error did not come down!

Comment: how do you initialize the weights (parameters) of your net at the beginning of training? from trained weights of caffe? random? zero?

Comment: I have added the initialization part of the code in the question. I am ctually using torch starter code but I want to change the AlexNet model the same as BVLC caffe and the benchmark that anyone is using now.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement AlexNet with PyTorch with:

```
import torch
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'alexnet', pretrained=True)
model.eval()
```

Or also you can check this repo from Github where the model is on h5 format for Tensorflow for easy implementation [here](https://github.com/Eduardo-RP/Pretrained-AlexNet-TensorFlow-with-Weights).